# Why does installing Wine in 12.04 from regular repo require removing non-related packages?

Tags: installation, software-center, wine

I've a fresh install of 12.04 64bit and have had only a few issues so far, all of them minor, until now that is.

In order to install WINE the software center is telling me I need to remove all of the following:

```
debhelper

gettext

intltool-debian

po-debconf

system-config-lvm

virtualbox-source
```

Where is this list coming from?  I only have the standard Canonical repo and the one for Canonical partners enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it asking to install new versions?  It doesn't require removing those packages.

I can tell you, if it's not upgrading version that those packages for sure do NOT conflict.

```
~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep wine
libkwineffects1abi3     install
wine-gecko1.4          install
wine-gecko1.4:i386     install
wine1.2                install
wine1.3                install
wine1.4                install
wine1.4-amd64          install
wine1.4-common         install
wine1.4-dbg            install
wine1.4-dev            install
wine1.4-i386:i386      install
winetricks             install

~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -f'test.txt'
debhelper                  install
gettext                    install
gettext-base               install
intltool-debian            install
libgettextpo0              install
libgettextpo0:i386         install
liblocale-gettext-perl     install
po-debconf                 install
```

After some observations in the comments, it looks like the problem might be a multi-arch dependency resolution/false conflict thing where it thinks i386 conflicts with x64.

Comment: Nope.  Said it needed to remove them, and after I authorized the WINE install they were gone.

Comment: You may be having a problem with the meta-package.  I didn't use that.  I used the main package `wine1.4-amd64`.  You should probably file a bug against the wine meta-package.

Comment: I tried both, and they both had the issue.  Here is the thing though; I hit apt-get to reinstall **debhelper** and sure enough, there was no conflict with installing it.  Also _gettextt_, _intltool-debian_, and _po-debconf_ all are auto-installed with it.

I now have WINE working along with the previously removed items and the system is stable.  I assume it must be some weird flagging issue in the Software Center.  I posted this question to see if this is a common problem with an easy solution...and apparently it's not common which is good for Ubuntu but bad for me!  lolz

Comment: I have the same issues with both, `wine` and `wine1.4` debs, however, `wine1.4-amd64 ` installed without conflicting anything.

Comment: Thanks for noting/bumping.  Might be a multi-arch dependency resolution/false conflict thing where it thinks i386 conflicts with x64.